# Testing AWS Lambda locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am about to write a server component targeting AWS lambda.  How do I develop this locally without having to deploy this every time I make a change?

Comment: It depends on how you wrote it. Are you using a deployment framework like serverless? Or, is just a plain javascript file?

Comment: Please provide more info about your project structure better if you can show some code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your project, the only thing I can recommend is for you to build a minimal web server application that will create your `event` object based on the `request` that you send.

In NodeJS, you can do this by writing a minimal `express` server that invokes your lambda handler in its route handler.

If you use [`serverless` framework](https://serverless.com/framework/), you can use a plugin called [`serverless-offline`](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sam Local](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local).

> Main features
>
> - Develop and test your Lambda functions locally with sam local and    Docker
> - Invoke functions from known event sources such as Amazon S3,    Amazon DynamoDB, Amazon Kinesis, etc.
> - Start local API Gateway from a SAM template, and quickly iterate over your functions hot-reloading
> - Validate SAM templates